# Why unhandledrejection event can not catch some Error in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

`unhandledrejection` can not catch some error in project build with `creat-react-app`.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/40kxy6761x)

```
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  alert(e.reason);
});

function onclick() {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    abcd(); // not alert
    // throw "abcd"; // alert
  });
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={onclick}>error</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While `unhandledrejection` can be used to catch unhandled promise rejection, you can use global error handler to catch unhandled errors

```
window.addEventListener('error', (errorEvent) => { 
  // handle errorEvent.error here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can catch rejected promises.

```
someFunctionReturnsPromise()
.then(resolvedValue => { /* do stuff */ })
.then(anotherResolvedValue => { /* do more stuff */ })
.catch(error => { /* handle any rejected promises here */ })
.finally(() => { /* you can do stuff here regardless of promise resolution */ });
```

[Handled Promise Exception](https://codesandbox.io/s/r0lw35mw14)

Although, I now realize you're asking why adding a listener for `unhandledrejection` doesn't catch errors in general.  It actually **does** work and catches the undefined function error thrown from `abcd()`.

[Unhandled event handler responding to promise rejection](https://codesandbox.io/s/oqon711q59)

<s>It should be noted that the event [`unhandledrejection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unhandledrejection) doesn't have universal browser support, in fact it **only** is supported in Chrome 49+.</s>

It should be noted that the event [`unhandledrejection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unhandledrejection) has fairly universal browser support now in [Chrome 49+, Edge 79+, Firefox 69+, Safari 11+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event#browser_compatibility).

Comment: Thanks for your apply. I know I can catch rejected promise with `.catch`. But I wonder why not dispatch `unhandledrejection` event  when a rejected promise not be catched

Comment: In your code example your code is choking on the undefined function before it has a chance to possibly return a promise rejection.  I added more explanation to my answer

Comment: Yes, `return Promise.reject('oops');` can alert. But `return Promise.reject(new Error("123"));` can not alert. Except `Error`, `TypeError` and `ReferenceError` can not either. see [the code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xrq90qww8z). So my question is why `unhandledrejection` can not catch these build in Error?

Comment: Your code sandbox actually works for me.  What browser are you using?  FYI, `unhandledrejection` only works in Chrome 49+.

Comment: @DrewReese `unhandledrejection` support Chrome `49`+,  Firefox `69`+, Edge `79`+ [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event)

Comment: @FilipSeman Thanks. You're also welcome to suggest edits yourself.